# Can you use the same Firebase auth for 2 different projects?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have two projects and I want to link them together.

I have auth set up on one of the projects and I want people from the other projects to log in to the same auth accounts.

Is that possible? If it is, can you explain how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do so. In your Firebase project, go to project settings, add a new app [android\iOS\web\unity] to your existing app.
Download the new google services.json and add it to your project.

Should work fine.

Comment: This is 2 different projects and I want to link them together.

Comment: Oh, I apologize, I misunderstood.

Comment: You can do it, you can configure an app to use multiple firebase projects. So you'd have to add the apps you want to access your shared project to that json services file, and to configure it inside your app to use firebase auth by pointing your users to the project that  handles the authentication. While keeping for example firestore separate for each project/app as it is currently.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad can you please share more information?